# Creating Winforms in Visual C++ for WinCE7 in Visual studio 2008 with WinCE7 platform builder

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I did a User interface in `Windows 7`. It contains buttons, labels, tabs and almost all features available in `VS2008` tool box.

The UI coding is done in `Visual C++`.

Now I want to port the same UI in `WinCE7`. I started the work by upgrading `VS2008 Sp1` and `Platform builder` for `WinCE7`.

Now I took a new `project->Visual c#->Smart Device->Device Application` and started the UI.

So I need to make a good amount of changes, also some functions are not available.
So am not able to complete the UI, no tabs selection is found and many others.

So can I get any ideas to port the same UI (created in `visual c++`) in `WinCE7`?

How can I create a new UI for `WinCE7` in `Visual c++` in `Visual Studio 2008` ?

Answer (score 3):

It is *sooooo* not that easy.  Windows CE is a small subset of Win32.  You have to pull in your code, hit build and then start fixing the errors.

If you used good separation of UI from business logic then it's probably easiest to just start an entirely new UI app for CE and reuse the business bits.  If your code it tightly coupled, well you've got a long road ahead.  There is no magic bullet for this one.

Comment: I am OK to start a new project and merge in the code from Windows 7 project but I need a starting point, a Windows Forms Application project in VC++ which I am not able to get"
So  1)Is it possible to create a Windows CE 7 Windows Forms application in VC++?? If yes, what is the starting point? I mean Which Project Type to select?
    2) If not possible what is the alternative for that. ?
    3) I have gone through Expression Blend , but my UI is little bit complex which i can't create in Expression Blend. So any other tools solution for this issue?

Comment: 4) Is there any way in Visual Studio 2012 to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing stuff here.
To develop applications for Windows CE 7 you don't need Platform Builder. You need it to build a configure an OS Image or to change a board-support-package (BSP) and debug it, including drivers.
For application development you need just Visual Studio 2008 professional and an SDK, provided by the device manufacturer.
Windows CE APIs are different from Win32 ones and may be seen as a subset of those.
You can create a new Windows CE application (with dialogs etc) using the new project dialog of visual studio 2008, just select the "Smart Device" category to see the templates you can use.
Porting existing code may require modification of C/C++ code (API changes) but also of the .rc file (resources) because Windows CE does not support all the features provided by Win32 resources.

Comment: Hai Valter..Thanks for the reply..  1) As u suggested I created Smart Device project and selected ' Device Application' which will give UI in C# and VB but not in Visual c++. How i can  get UI for Visual C++ which will  open in WinCE7.

Comment: If you installed Visual C++ you should have categories also for that. How did you implemented the UI in your app? You used just plain basic Win32 API or you used some additional libs like MFC, ATL/TWL, QT etc?

Comment: 1)For Windows 7 i directly started like:New Project-> Visual c++-> Windows Forms Application and the UI will work fine in Windows 7 machine. For WinCE 7, i made like New Project-> Visual c++-> Smart Device->Win32 Smart Device Project . But they will not have any user interface in the project.  2) I just used plain basic Win32 API only.